# What are all the different passwords and passcodes needed to fully setup iOS?

Tags: ios, password

The other day I was surprised to have to remember my restrictions passcode when reseting my iPhone. What are all the difference passwords and passcode needed to fully setup an iOS device? And which ones can be different with different IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the ones I know of

- iOS Passcode (used for lock screen, approving changes to security settings, Apple Pay, and resetting a device)
- Restrictions passcode (Used for locking out apps and features)
- Guided Access passcode (I think this is different from the restrictions passcode but I'm not sure)
- iCloud account and password (Used for syncing data, iMessage, Find my iPhone)
- iTunes/AppStore/iBooks account and password (Can be different than iCloud)
- Apple Music account and password
- Encrypted iTunes backup (I guess this follows the device around from one computer to another)
- Password protected notes in the Notes app.

Comment: As a side note. All of these are currently completely optional to use!

Answer (score 1):

Passcode usually refers to the 4-digit lock code (unless you are using a more complex 6-digits passcode) and password typically refers to your Apple ID password.

Moreover, the password is associated with your Apple ID and is what is used to access Apple services such as iTunes and App Store purchases. It is also used when turning off find my iPhone and iCloud as well as to erase your device and restore to factory condition. The passcode is associated with your device and is used to secure it from unauthorized use.